# Goggle Sheets Dashboard Comparison Chart feature

Tags: google-sheets, dashboard

I don't know if this is possible, or how to tackle it.

I have a table with 9 columns the first is Name-Eng-Esp-Fra-Ger-Rus-Ukr-Chi-Hin

On the dashboard I would like to have viewer select the column Data comparison. I.E. I want to see a comparison chart for the German column and the Russian column. Then the chart now reflects a two bar graph comparing just those.

Everytime I think I know how approach it I get lost in the weeds...

|  | English | German | French | Chinese | Ukrainian | Hindi | Spanish | Russian |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Please | 5 | 7 | 1 | 2 | 8 | 2 | 9 | 6 |
| Thank you | 1 | 6 | 3 | 4 | 12 | 5 | 7 | 3 |
| Good Day | 3 | 3 | 9 | 8 | 2 | 4 | 12 | 2 |
| Your Welcome | 2 | 10 | 4 | 1 | 5 | 7 | 1 | 5 |

Comment: What data are you comparing?

Comment: It's numerical.  Name = Common Expression.  Data = number of references  in the given language

Comment: [edit] your question to include a table with a minimal sample of your data and also another table with your expected results.  You can use the  [Markdown Tables Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) to assist you.

Comment: Thanks for the "Markdown" and table edit suggestion, to help clarify my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I mocked up an example based off the data you provided [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eDx602ChtJO_kx4D7shd_b5OZf6pOEmUNqWLB4uL0pk/edit#gid=0).

Essentially, you want to create a dynamic data range based on user input. So say you have a [drop down](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/186103?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop) in B10 and you have your full data set (including column headers and row labels) in the range A1:I5. Initially B10 is empty, but if a user selects Chinese (which should identically match one of your column headers), you can grab the data corresponding to that row with the following formula: `=iferror(index($B$2:$I$5,,match(B$10,$B$1:$I$1,0)))` (with the formula ia B11).

In case you are unfamiliar with some of the formulas (starting from the inside out):

- match - just searches for the position of a particular item in a range (in this case searching for the text "Chinese" within the range of column headers from the full data set)
- index - traditionally this grabs one item in a range according to a provided row and cell index, but if you skip the row argument and only provide a column argument, then it returns the entire column
- iferror - simply returns a blank cell if there is an error (just for a nicer UI)

If you connect the chart to the range that corresponds to the dynamically populated data then the chart will automatically update when the user makes changes. A couple notes:

- The title will not update automatically, so you'll want to make that generic if you use it at all (the legend though will update accordingly)
- In case the data is uneven, you'll want the data range on the chart to reflect the largest possible range of data so nothing gets accidentally clipped.